# Get prototype inside an eventhandler

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I'm trying to get the prototype inside an event handler.

```
function Post(){
    this.post;
    this.deleteButton;
}
Post.prototype.delete = function(){

    var OBJ = this;//this is not the prototype, instead it is the HTML element (deleteButton)
    $(OBJ.container).remove();
}
Post.prototype.createPost = function(){

    var OBJ = this;
    OBJ.post = document.createElement('div');
    OBJ.post.className = 'post'
    OBJ.deleteButton = document.createElement('div');
    OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', OBJ.delete, false);
}
```

Look at the comment section above. A delete handler is declared as a prototype method to `Post`. And I assign the delete handler to a delete button. The thing is that `this`becomes the HTML Element instead of the object prototype.

EDIT:

I also want to have the opportunity to remove the delete handler

Comment: Consider putting the *createPost* function body inside the constructor so you don't need 2 calls to create a *Post* instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    OBJ.delete();
}, false);
```

But `OBJ` is not the prototype, it refers to the instance.

**Update:** If you want to remove it too, store a reference to it:

```
this.deleteHandler_ = function() {
    OBJ.delete();
};
OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', this.deleteHandler_, false);
```

Somewhere else:

```
this.deleteButton.removeEventListener('click', this.deleteHandler_);
```

Comment: Kling Forgot to mention that I also want to remove the event handler

Comment: @Woho87: Then store a reference to it.

Comment: small additional detail: MSIE model requires to use oElt.attachEvent instead of oElt.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
var onDelete = $.proxy(OBJ.delete, OBJ);
OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', onDelete, false);
```

There's also ECMAScript 5 [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
var onDelete = OBJ.delete.bind(OBJ);
OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', onDelete, false);
```

To remove the listener:

```
OBJ.deleteButton.removeEventListener('click', onDelete, false);
```

Comment: @Felix Kling, it completely devaluates the answer.

Comment: No removeEventListener example?

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.prototype.createPost = function(){

    var OBJ = this;
    OBJ.post = document.createElement('div');
    OBJ.post.className = 'post'
    OBJ.deleteButton = document.createElement('div');
    OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){OBJ.delete();}, false);
}
```

If you are using jquery you can use the proxy method:

```
  OBJ.deleteButton.addEventListener('click',$.proxy(OBJ.delete,OBJ), false);
```

Comment: I will get trouble to remove the event handler with this solution, don't I?